# Rewriting $(\frac{1}{32})^x\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^{(9x-5)}$ in the form $(\frac12)^{f(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Been having a bit of trouble with these problems. How would you go about solving this problem?

> Rewrite $\left(\dfrac{1}{32}\right)^x \cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{(9x-5)}$ in the form $\left(\dfrac12\right)^{f(x)}$

Comment: First... please do try to write things in an unambiguous way.  `1/2^9x-5` could well be interpreted as $\dfrac{1}{2^9}x-5$ rather than $\dfrac{1}{2^{9x-5}}$.  Use more parentheses, or better yet, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to properly format mathematics here.

Comment: As to the content of your question... recall that $a^b\cdot a^c = a^{b+c}$, that for positive real $a$ we have $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, and that $\frac{1}{32}=\frac{1}{2^5}$

Comment: Oh, I got it now, thanks! The exponents were really messing me up there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from index laws you can show
$$\left(\frac{1}{32}\right)^x=\left(\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^5\right)^x=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5x}$$

so for you expression
$$\left(\frac{1}{32}\right)^x\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(9x-5)}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(9x-5)}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(5x+9x-5)}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{(14x-5)}=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{f(x)}$$
where $f(x)=14x-5$

hopefully that helps

Comment: Thanks for breaking down the problem for me, this really helps!

Comment: Be careful of writing ${\frac{1}{2}}^5$ as it might incorrectly be interpreted as $\dfrac{~1^5~}{2}$ which is simply $\dfrac{1}{2}$ as opposed to $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^5$ which is $\dfrac{1}{32}$.  Better to use parentheses.  Typesetting note for parentheses, use `\left(` and `\right)` to insist the parentheses are large enough to encapsulate what appears between them.

Comment: Good to know. The formatting tends to be pretty confusing XD

Answer (score 1):

$32= 2^5$
Hence $32^{-x}=2^{-5x}$ or $\frac {1}{2}^{5x}$
Therefore the answer is $\frac {1}{2}^{14x-5}$